# Nginx redirect sub.domain.com/users/page/somename to somename.sub.domain.com

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I've been trying to redirect http://sub.domain.com/users/page/somename to http://somename.sub.domain.com etc.

Any pointers?

Comment: If you post what you have been trying, that'd help to answer. Didn't you try any code at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sub.domain.com;

  location ~ ^/users/page/(.*)$ {                                                                                                                 
    return 301  http://$1.sub.domain.com/;                                                                                                         
  }
}
```